# netCDF convert to NaN for conditional

Tags: python, numpy, nan, netcdf4

I want to convert values from a netCDF file into NaN called `LandMask_NaN` when they are greater than zero. However, there seems to be a type mismatch between `LandMask` and what numpy will convert to NaNs. Any help much appreciated, code and info below:

```
 import netCDF4 as nc
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import csv as cs
 import pandas as pd

ncfile = nc.Dataset('C:\Users\mmso2\Google Drive\ENVI_I-PAC_2007_10_21_21_22_47.nc')#office machine

SARwind = ncfile.variables['sar_wind']
ModelWind = ncfile.variables['model_speed']
LON = ncfile.variables['longitude']
LAT = ncfile.variables['latitude']
LandMask = ncfile.variables['mask']

#clean the data of values = 70

SARwind_nan = SARwind[:].copy()
SARwind_nan[SARwind_nan == 0.0] = np.nan
SARwind_nan[SARwind_nan == 70.0] = np.nan

#clear the data of values where there is land
# % pos = land; neg = water

LandMask_NaN = LandMask[:].copy()
#LandMask_NaN[int(float(LandMask_NaN))]### will not convert
LandMask_NaN[LandMask_NaN >0.0] = np.nan #error here
```

The error I get is

```
#error
line 37, in <module>
LandMask_NaN[LandMask_NaN >= 0.0] = np.nan
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

When trying

```
LandMask_NaN[int(float(LandMask_NaN))]
```

or

```
LandMask_NaN[float(int(LandMask_NaN))]
```

before trying to convert to NaN, I get

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

When checking for the type of LandMask I get

`<type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>`

I am not sure how to find out the variable type?

Update: Details of nc variables

```
NetCDF dimension information:
    Name: x
        size: 848
        type:       WARNING: x does not contain variable attributes
    Name: y
        size: 972
        type:       WARNING: y does not contain variable attributes
    Name: xfit
        size: 6
        type:       WARNING: xfit does not contain variable attributes
NetCDF variable information:
    Name: acquisition_time
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float64')
        units: u'seconds since 2000-01-01 00:00:00'
        long_name: u'Acqusition time in Julian seconds since 2000-01-01T00:00:00Z'
        standard_name: u'time'
        calendar: u'gregorian'
    Name: nx
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('int32')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Number of elements in this file'
    Name: ny
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('int32')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Number of lines in this file'
    Name: nx0
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('int32')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Number of elements in SIO file'
    Name: ny0
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('int32')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Number of lines in SIO file'
    Name: nx00
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('int32')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Number of elements in original SAR file'
    Name: ny00
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('int32')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Number of lines in original SAR file'
    Name: xn
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'1'
    Name: yn
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'1'
    Name: line_size
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'm'
        long_name: u'Line size'
    Name: pixel_size
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'm'
        long_name: u'Pixel size'
    Name: model_time_js
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float64')
        units: u'seconds since 2000-01-01 00:00:00'
        long_name: u'Model time julian seconds since 2000-01-01T00:00:00Z'
    Name: model_time_js_tau
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float64')
        units: u'seconds since 2000-01-01 00:00:00'
        long_name: u'Model time plus tau julian seconds since 2000-01-01T00:00:00Z'
    Name: upper_left_longitude
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'degrees_east'
        long_name: u'degrees'
    Name: upper_right_longitude
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'degrees_east'
        long_name: u'degrees'
    Name: upper_left_latitude
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'degrees_north'
        long_name: u'degrees'
    Name: upper_right_latitude
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'degrees_north'
        long_name: u'degrees'
    Name: start_center_longitude
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'degrees_east'
        long_name: u'degrees'
    Name: start_center_latitude
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'degrees_north'
        long_name: u'degrees'
    Name: scene_center_longitude
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'degrees_east'
        long_name: u'degrees'
    Name: scene_center_latitude
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'degrees_north'
        long_name: u'degrees'
    Name: lower_left_longitude
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'degrees_east'
        long_name: u'degrees'
    Name: lower_right_longitude
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'degrees_east'
        long_name: u'degrees'
    Name: lower_left_latitude
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'degrees_north'
        long_name: u'degrees'
    Name: lower_right_latitude
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'degrees_north'
        long_name: u'degrees'
    Name: end_center_longitude
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'degrees_east'
        long_name: u'degrees'
    Name: end_center_latitude
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'degrees_north'
        long_name: u'degrees'
    Name: northernmost_latitude
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'degrees_north'
        long_name: u'degrees'
    Name: southernmost_latitude
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'degrees_north'
        long_name: u'degrees'
    Name: easternmost_longitude
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'degrees_east'
        long_name: u'degrees'
    Name: westernmost_longitude
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'degrees_east'
        long_name: u'degrees'
    Name: nrcs_slope
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float32')
    Name: nrcs_bias
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1.0
        type: dtype('float32')
    Name: sigma
        dimensions: (u'y', u'x')
        size: 824256
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Normalized Radar Cross Section.'
        coordinates: u'longitude latitude'
    Name: sar_wind
        dimensions: (u'y', u'x')
        size: 824256
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'm s-1'
        long_name: u'SAR-derived wind speed at 10-m height neutral stability'
        standard_name: u'wind_speed'
        coordinates: u'longitude latitude'
    Name: input_dir
        dimensions: (u'y', u'x')
        size: 824256
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'degrees'
        long_name: u'Interpolated directions used for wind inversion'
        coordinates: u'longitude latitude'
    Name: model_speed
        dimensions: (u'y', u'x')
        size: 824256
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'm s-1'
        long_name: u'Interpolated model wind speed (=1 for non model directions)'
        standard_name: u'wind_speed'
        coordinates: u'longitude latitude'
    Name: mask
        dimensions: (u'y', u'x')
        size: 824256
        type: dtype('int16')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Interpolated land mask distance from shore line. Positive values land / Negative value water'
        flag_values: array([-1,  0,  1], dtype=int16)
        flag_meanings: u'water shore land'
        coordinates: u'longitude latitude'
    Name: longitude
        dimensions: (u'y', u'x')
        size: 824256
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'degrees_east'
        long_name: u'Longitude array in decimal degrees'
        standard_name: u'longitude'
    Name: latitude
        dimensions: (u'y', u'x')
        size: 824256
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'degrees_north'
        long_name: u'Latitude array in decimal degrees'
        standard_name: u'latitude'
    Name: rlook
        dimensions: (u'y', u'x')
        size: 824256
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'degrees'
        long_name: u'Radar look direction array in decimal degrees from North'
        coordinates: u'longitude latitude'
    Name: incid
        dimensions: (u'y', u'x')
        size: 824256
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'degrees'
        long_name: u'Incident angle array in degrees from nadir'
        coordinates: u'longitude latitude'
    Name: icemask
        dimensions: (u'y', u'x')
        size: 824256
        type: dtype('int16')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Ice mask 0=no_data 1=water 2=land 3=sea_ice 4=snow'
        flag_values: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int16)
        flag_meanings: u'no_data water land sea_ice snow'
        coordinates: u'longitude latitude'
    Name: lon_coef
        dimensions: (u'xfit',)
        size: 6
        type: dtype('float64')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Coefficients to compute longitude in degs from pixel/lines'
    Name: lon_xexp
        dimensions: (u'xfit',)
        size: 6
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Longitude pixel exponents'
    Name: lon_yexp
        dimensions: (u'xfit',)
        size: 6
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Longitude line exponents'
    Name: lat_coef
        dimensions: (u'xfit',)
        size: 6
        type: dtype('float64')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Coefficients to compute latitude in degs from pixel/lines'
    Name: lat_xexp
        dimensions: (u'xfit',)
        size: 6
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Latitude pixel exponents'
    Name: lat_yexp
        dimensions: (u'xfit',)
        size: 6
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Latitude line exponents'
    Name: i_coef
        dimensions: (u'xfit',)
        size: 6
        type: dtype('float64')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Coefficients to compute pixel from longitue/latitude'
    Name: i_xexp
        dimensions: (u'xfit',)
        size: 6
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Pixel longitude exponents'
    Name: i_yexp
        dimensions: (u'xfit',)
        size: 6
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Pixel latitude exponents'
    Name: j_coef
        dimensions: (u'xfit',)
        size: 6
        type: dtype('float64')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Coefficients to compute line from longitue/latitude'
    Name: j_xexp
        dimensions: (u'xfit',)
        size: 6
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Line longitude exponents'
    Name: j_yexp
        dimensions: (u'xfit',)
        size: 6
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Line latitude exponents'
    Name: incid_coef
        dimensions: (u'xfit',)
        size: 6
        type: dtype('float64')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Coefficients to compute incid in degs from pixel/lines'
    Name: incid_xexp
        dimensions: (u'xfit',)
        size: 6
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Incid pixel exponents'
    Name: incid_yexp
        dimensions: (u'xfit',)
        size: 6
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Incid line exponents'
    Name: rlook_coef
        dimensions: (u'xfit',)
        size: 6
        type: dtype('float64')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Coefficients to compute radar look direction in degs from pixel/lines'
    Name: rlook_xexp
        dimensions: (u'xfit',)
        size: 6
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Radar look direction pixel exponents'
    Name: rlook_yexp
        dimensions: (u'xfit',)
        size: 6
        type: dtype('float32')
        units: u'1'
        long_name: u'Radar look direction line exponents'
```

Answer (score 1):

It'll be helpful if you share the netcdf file, but here are a few ideas of what's going on:

Variables are not currently being read-in as numpy arrays. You need to add indexing parameters to cast them to arrays. Without the file, I'm not sure what they are, but surely some are multi-dimensional.  For example:

```
SARwind = ncfile.variables['sar_wind'][:,:]
ModelWind = ncfile.variables['model_speed'][:,:]
LON = ncfile.variables['longitude'][:]
LAT = ncfile.variables['latitude'][:]
LandMask = ncfile.variables['mask'][:,:]
```

Then you can simply assign `SARwind` to a new variable `SARWind_nan` and input `nan` values as you have been doing.

```
SARWind_nan = SARwind
SARwind_nan[SARwind_nan == 0.0] = np.nan
SARwind_nan[SARwind_nan == 70.0] = np.nan
```

With `LandMask` properly read-in (again, I think this is very likely 2D, not 1D as you have), you can similarly assign to a new variable `LandMask_nan` and input `nan` values.  Double check the type of `LandMask`, it's possibly an integer. [ncdump](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/workshops/2011/utilities/Ncdump.html) or [ncks](http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html#ncks-netCDF-Kitchen-Sink) are good tools for examining netcdf contents.

```
LandMask_NaN = LandMask
LandMask_NaN[LandMask_NaN > 0.0] = np.nan
```

Comment: Thank you @N1B4. I will give that a try. How do I attach my netCDF file to the question?

Comment: Your suggestions make sense, yet I still have the problem of `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`. I am happy to share the netCDF file but I am not sure how to do that on here?

Comment: If possible, put the file on a public storage site (eg Dropbox) and paste the link here for us to access it.  Additionally, it will help to provide an ncdump of the file to show us details of the variables and dimensions.

Comment: I don't have permission to share the file unfortunately, however I've added some details on the nc file variables above.

Comment: Can you post just a snippet of the file?  Don't need the whole thing, just a few grid cells to work with.  Otherwise, showing us an ncdump of its contents will also help.

Comment: Cheers I've added an Ncdump above.